# Non singular complex projective variety is a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am a beginner student in algebraic geometry, and I wanted to understand how an non-singular complex projective variety $X$ a smooth manifold when given the subspace topology coming from $\mathcal C^n$? 
I can see that we can cover $X$ by affine sets but are these sets charts?

I would prefer an answer which does not use any language of scheme and is understandable with minimal knowledge of algebraic geometry.

Comment: There are details in the answer to this question which are sensitive to your particular definitions. Please provide your definition of a variety (in the original question).

Comment: variety will be zero locus of homogeneous polynomials

Answer (score 6):

A smooth (irreducible) variety is locally cut out by polynomials $f_1,...,f_k\in \mathbb{C}[z_1,\dots, z_n]$ whose Jacobian matrix $\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_j}\right)$
 has full rank, which is $n-r$, where $r=n-k$ is the dimension of the variety. (This is the Jacobian criterion for smoothness. This can be found in chapter 1 of Hartshorne, for instance.) These polynomial functions are, in particular, holomorphic functions, and so having a full rank Jacobian allows one to apply the holomorphic analogue of the implicit function theorem to get local holomoprhic charts for your variety.

Edit: as requested, here is a fleshing out of the last statement. I will point out that the argument is essentially the same in the $C^\infty$-manifold case, replacing holomorphic with $C^\infty$.

Let $X$ be the affine variety in question. The implicit function theorem (Proposition 1.1.11 in Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry* text) is the following:

**Theorem.** Let $U\subset \mathbb C^n$ be an open subset and let $f:U\to \mathbb{C}^k$ be a holomorphic map, where $n\geq k$. Suppose $z_0\in U$ is a point such that 
$$
  \det\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_j}(z_0)\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq k} \neq 0.
$$
Then there exist open subsets $U_1 \subset \mathbb C^{n-k}$, $U_2\subset \mathbb{C}^k$  and a holomorphic map $g: U_1 \to U_2$ such that $U_1\times U_2 \subset U$ and $f(z) = f(z_0)$ if and only if $g(z_{k+1}, \dots, z_n) = (z_1,\dots, z_k)$.

Note that the condition on the determinant I wrote in the theorem really says that the Jacobian has maximal rank, with the extra assumption that we ordered the functions $f_1, \dots, f_k$ so that the pivot columns of the Jacobian appear in the first $k$ columns.

Furthermore, to make this a bit more intuitive, the number $k$ is the codimension of $X$, and $n-k$ is the dimension of $X$. So, you can expect that $U_1$ is going to be the coordinate chart for $X$.

Here's how: define the map $U_1 \to X\cap U$ by $(z_{k+1}, \dots, z_n) \mapsto (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n,g(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n))$. This is the map $\text{id}\times g: U_1 \to U_1 \times U_2$. (I now realize Huybrechts' notation is funny: he's writing coordinates as $z=(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n, z_1, \dots, z_k)$. I will stick to this convention to avoid clashes with his conventions.)

A point $z' = (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n, z_1, \dots, z_k)$ in the image of $\text{id}\times g$ satisfies the requirement $g(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n) = (z_1,\dots,z_k)$, which implies 
$$f\bigg((\text{id}\times g) (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n)\bigg) = f(z_0)=0$$ by the "if" part of the theorem. Therefore $\text{id}\times g$ is well-defined (i.e. it actually maps into $X\cap U$ and not just some random spot in $U$).

Clearly $\text{id}\times g$ is holomorphic. The inverse to $\text{id}\times g$ is the projection map $\pi: X\cap U \to U_1$, given by $\pi:(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n, z_1, \dots, z_k) =( z_{k+1},\dots, z_n)$, which is also holomorphic. To verify that it is an inverse, observe that 
$$
  \pi \circ (\text{id}\times g) (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n) = (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n) 
$$
holds because $\pi$ only looks at the first $n-k$ coordinates. On the other hand, writing $z' = (z_{k+1},\dots, z_n, z_1, \dots, z_k)$ again,
$$
  (\text{id}\times g)\circ \pi (z') = (\text{id}\times g)(z_{k+1},\dots,z_n) = \bigg(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n, g(z_{k+1},\dots, z_n)\bigg) = z'
$$
which holds by the "only if" part of the theorem: $z'\in X\cap U$ means $f(z')=0$, which says $g(z_{k+1}, \dots, z_n) = (z_1,\dots, z_k)$, granting the final equality in this equation. This establishes that $\text{id}\times g: U_1 \to X\cap U$ is a biholomorphic map, so $U_1$ is a coordinate chart for $X$.

Comment: could you please write the argument in the last statement in a more detailed way

Comment: are you taking k=n-r?

Comment: Yes. I just realized I used two different letters. I will edit this.

Comment: Dear Andrew, Huybrechts's book, didn't say $ g(z_{k+1},…,z_n)=(z_1,…,z_n)$, instead, it says that $ g(z_{n+1},…,z_m)=(z_1,…,z_n)$.

Comment: @Danny Thanks for pointing that out. I'll need to modify my argument slightly.

Comment: @Danny Also, if my answer solves your problem, don't forget to press "accept answer."

Comment: @Andrew I would like to accept your nice answer, however I didn't post this question. Indeed, I have a question, can I say that the smooth structure, i.e. the transition functions are smooth, follows from the biholomorphism?

Comment: @Danny My apologies! I hadn't noticed you weren't the OP. But to answer your question, yes the biholomorphism grants the smooth manifold structure on the variety. This is due to the fact in complex analysis that holomorphic functions are smooth.